# Does Evernote still support the C++ API?

Tags: c++, evernote

I wanted to extend an existing C++ application to use Evernote. I have downloaded the C++ SDK for Evernote and the Windows SDK for Evernote. The C++ SDK does not have any documentation. It just consists of a series of C++ files dating back to 2013. The Windows SDK documentation relates to C#. A great language, but not what my existing code is written in.

I have built the Thrift Library and linked it with my test application. I can get it to make an HTTP connection, but checkVersion gives me an EOF exception from THttpTransport::refill.

```
   boost::shared_ptr   User_Store_Http_Client = boost::shared_ptr(new THttpClient("sandbox.evernote.com", 443, "/edam/user"));
   boost::shared_ptr User_Store_Protocol = boost::shared_ptr(new TBinaryProtocol(User_Store_Http_Client));
   UserStoreClient* User_Store = new UserStoreClient(User_Store_Protocol, User_Store_Protocol);
   User_Store_Http_Client->open();
   User_Store->checkVersion("MyApp", evernote::edam::g_UserStore_constants.EDAM_VERSION_MAJOR, evernote::edam::g_UserStore_constants.EDAM_VERSION_MINOR);
```

The Windows SDK talks about EnSession objects, which don't appear in the C++ SDK? I am assuming that the C++ SDK is a raw EDAM implementation and that the C# API has a higher level to it.

Does anyone have a working example of C++ code that would help me get started? Where should I go for help on using Evernote from C++? Am I flogging a dead horse with this?

I am struggling to understand how I should use the Evernote C++ API and would appreciate some help.

Comment: If you want you could use the C# API: create a C++/CLI project, which allows you to use the C# API, and which also can export C++ classes/functions or even plain C. Which in turn you can consume in your current C++ code.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not trying to create a new project, I'm trying to extend an existing unmanaged C++ project. Otherwise I would have created a new C# project.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I'm just pointing out that if for some reason it's not possible to achive what you want with the C++ API, there are ways around it.

Comment: I changed the port number to 80 and now this bit works. So now I have to figure out how to do authentication in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I found this SDK

https://github.com/d1vanov/QEverCloud

Looks promising so far.